# Call async method properly on WP8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, async-await

I'm sorry to ask such a basic/stupid question, but I'm lost. I've spent 3 days working on this stupid problem and can't find a solution.

My problem is that the program freezes as soon as async methods are involved.

My code is below. First, I define some global parameters, then in public MainPage(), the first task is to call method "OpenFile()" to get information from a .txt file (containing coutries and correponding capitals)

```
namespace WorldCapitalsv2
{

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
//Some global parameters    
string paysATrouver = null; string capitaleATrouver = null;    
    int scoreJoueur; int nombreParties; int HighScore; Random rand = new Random();int nbCountries;
    List<Pays> listCountries = new List<Pays>();
    HashSet<int> checkRnd = new HashSet<int>();
    int[] propositionRepNb = new int[4];

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        InitializeComponent();
        openFile(); //Program freezes here :(
        nbCountries = listCountries.Count;
    }

    async void openFile()
    {
        Uri capitaleFileLoc = new Uri("ms-appdata://Capitale.txt");
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(capitaleFileLoc);//.AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
        var list = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);//.AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
        foreach (string country in list)
        {
            string[] countrycap = country.Split('\t');
            listCountries.Add(new Pays() { nomPays = countrycap[0], Capitale = countrycap[1] });
        }
    }
```

It is very frustrating, because it is otherwise working like a charm, e.g. rather than using a .txt file I put the information in the main program, by putting :

```
List<Pays> listePays = new List<Pays>(){
            new Pays() {nomPays="France", Capitale="Paris"},
... etc
```

However, i'd rather call and read an external file.

I have tried to add an output parameter to my async openFile method, e.g :

```
        async Task<List<Pays>> openFile()
{
Code;
return ListCountries;
}
```

And tried to get the data in MainPage() with :

```
  Task<List<Pays>> listePaysT = ouvreFichier();
        listePaysT.Start();
        listePaysT.Wait();
        listePays = listePaysT.Result;
```

But this solution is not working ....

Also, if I try to call my method openFile() with an await it will not work (I understood await calls are not possible in the MainPage()).

I'd be forever gratefull to anybody who could help solve this problem. Thanks.

More details below : here is the interface: a very basic 1 page only app.

```
<Page
x:Class="WorldCapitalsv2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:WorldCapitalsv2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TexteAppTitle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,585" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="World Capitals" Width="400" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" FontSize="48"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_prop1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,261,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="70" Width="343" FontSize="24" Click="Reponse1"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_prop2" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,326,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="70" Width="343" FontSize="24" Click="Reponse2"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_prop3" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,391,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="70" Width="343" FontSize="24" Click="Reponse3"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_prop4" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,457,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="70" Width="343" FontSize="24" Click="Reponse4"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="labelQuestion" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,97,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="380" Height="101"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="labelScore" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,532,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" Height="101"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="labelHighScore" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="223,532,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" Height="101"/>

</Grid>
```

I've put all my methods in the "MainPage.xaml.cs" and nothing more than initially created by VS in "App.xaml.cs"

Comment: You can use await in MainPage, and you should be using it here.

Comment: I tried to add ".AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false)" hopping that it would somehow "deactivate" the async and allow me to call the method without "await" ... but it did not work

Comment: @pumpkinszwan: You can't use `await` within a constructor.

Comment: Correction - I think you were talking about the constructor, but I interpreted it as the page itself. The constructor can't be async. But you can call an async method from the constructor.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry but I tried to write "await openFile()", and VS returns an error "the await operator can only be used in an async method"... if I try to modify Main page like this : "async public MainPage()", I get a warning : "async is not valid for this element" ... Did I forget a "using" statement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
listePaysT.Wait();
```

That will block until the task has completed... so you're blocking your UI thread. Worse, the async methods will need to return to the UI thread in order to continue, so you've got a deadlock.

`Task.Wait()` and `Task.Result` can only be used *very* carefully.

You should think about exactly what you want to happen. You can't make the constructor async, but you could potentially make the page constructor complete and *then* call a separate async method to populate its data. (It's not clear why you've got all this code in the UI layer anyway - shouldn't it be in the view-model?)

Basically, you should think about what you want to happen before the data is available - do you want the UI to be present but not contain the data, or do you want the `MainPage` to only be available after the data has been fetched?

You can *sort of* mimic an async constructor with a static async method:

```
public static async MainPage CreatePageAsync()
{
    var ret = new MainPage(); // This would be the normal UI code
    await ret.LoadDataAsync(); // This would asynchronously fetch the data
}
```

Also note that currently you're calling `InitializeComponent` twice, which can't be a good idea...

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer. I tried to remove the .Wait()... but something still freezes the program... If I do not want to use this sequence :   Task<List<Pays>> listePaysT = ouvreFichier();     listePaysT.Start(); listePaysT.Wait();listePays = listePaysT.Result; .. how should I proceed ?

Comment: @Mike: Well if you *just* remove the `Wait()`, then `Result` will block in the same way. Basically you can't do that. It really doesn't help that we've got no idea where that code is - you've just given us the snippet, but we don't know what method it's from.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. Seems to me that I first need to learn more basic stuff. What I want, is to fetch the data to construct a list of countries/capital, before the first question is asked and answered. My program is basic: it loads and displays a country name, and below 4 possible answers.

Comment: I'm a bit ashamed to ask, but what do you mean by "UI layer" vs. "view-model" do you mean MainPage.xaml.cs vs. App.xaml.cs ?

Comment: @Mike: No, I mean the view model part of the MVVM model/view/view-model architecture, which is how Windows Phone applications are intended to be written - keep your presentation logic away from the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change that async void to async Task> that you tried earlier.
Then put the code after InitializeComponent from the constructor into another method (async) and call it from the constructor.

Instead of calling openfile(), change it to something like listCountries = await (openFile());

What causes the freeze is that you do not wait for openfile to complete before trying to use the results of it.

You should read up a little on async because you're doing it wrong :)
Have a look here: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

You shouldn't use 'async void' because there is no way to know when the async work is complete, and the main reason for async is to let long-running code do its thing and report back to the code that is waiting for it to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Thaks to your help, and after a few hours, I found out how to proceed. 1/ I created a load button/method to open the .txt file. Then, I split the openFile method in two separate methods (1 for opening and 1 for spliting). Instead of being void, I also added Task<> to get return values, so the method becomes :

```
    public async Task<StorageFile> openFile()
    {
        Uri capitaleFileLoc = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Capitale.txt");
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(capitaleFileLoc);//.AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return file;
    }

    public async Task<List<Pays>> splitFile(StorageFile file)
    {
       var list = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);//.AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
       List<Pays> listCountries = new List<Pays>();

       foreach (string country in list)
       {
           string[] countrycap = country.Split('\t');
           listCountries.Add(new Pays() { nomPays = countrycap[0], Capitale = countrycap[1] });
       }
       labelHighScore.Text =  listCountries[2].nomPays;
       return listCountries;
    }
```

Once this is done, the calling method is written :

```
public async void load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       StorageFile file = await openFile();        
       List<Pays> listCountries = await splitFile(file);
}
```

Here everything works fine. The file is loaded and "listCountries" contains all the required data. (Now I have different and new problems in my program but nothing as complicated hopefully).
Thanks again and I hope my question will be helpful to somebody.